# Problems with simple PDO output

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the SID from another page and then use this simple PDO statement below so I can get the post name. The SID is the post ID number. I have that so I should be able to get the post name column from that table. Can anyone see why my code will not display the post_name? All it says is "your post is entitle  ."

```
//get SID from other page
$the_SID = ( isset( $_GET['textid'] ) ) ? $_GET['textid'] : false;


$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
posts.PID,
posts.post_name    
FROM posts
WHERE posts.PID = :postid");

$results->bindParam(':postid', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 

$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo var_dump($row);
?>


Your post is entitled <b><? $row[0]['post_name']; ?>. 


//var_dump results
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
[“PID”]=>
string(1) “1”
[“post_name”]=>
string(19) “The Beginning”
}
}
```

Comment: what var_dump shows?

Comment: Please use indentation.

Comment: There is no indentation on a var_dump

Comment: Since when does `var_dump` display curly quotes instead of ASCII doublequotes?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. That's exactly how the output was for my var_dump. I copied and pasted as is from the output to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing html and php?  You're not actually echoing our your row result.

Change this:

```
Your post is entitled <b><? $row[0]['post_name']; ?>.
```

To:

```
Your post is entitled <b><?php echo $row[0]['post_name']; ?>.
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I guess I'm just tired.